# The way to freeze the camera preview

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, preview

I Implemented a system to take photo in my apps with Android class Camera. All run well but after taken photo I want show the preview at the user and let him the choice to save the picture or cancel it. The problem I have is with the preview. The preview appears after the `mCamera.startPreview();` and is shown during only some little seconds with or without `mCamera.stopPreview();`. I would extend display time or freeze preview until some certain  event.

Somebody know a way to congeal the preview for a time ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android (Camera) - How to syncronize stopPreview() with onPictureTaken()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924038/android-camera-how-to-syncronize-stoppreview-with-onpicturetaken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to fetch the image taken and display it.

Comment: I had begun to use this way when I posted this question. But why used an ImageView when the Camera class give you a preview after every picture taken ? That's why I posted this question.

But meanwhile responses, I found a way to use the camera preview. In the event listener "onPictureTaken" , I just stop the camera and the preview stays on the screen. To take a picture again, I just put a "retry" button for run the camera again. And on this event button I restart the camera and the camera removes the preview. And all actions to take picture and save it run todly and normally.
Thanks.

Comment: I have a device (Huawei U8650 running android 2.3.3) where the method camera.stopPreview() makes the surfaceview completely black, instead of freezing the image. I want to know if this issue happens just with this device, or it's a common issue.

On the other devices I have the approach you mentioned works well.

Answer (score 0):

The preview will be stopped after you take a picture.  However, the stopped preview does not necessarily correspond to the picture that was actually taken.  For that, you'll have to fetch the picture and display it through an ImageView or something similar.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29)

> This method is only valid when preview is active (after
>   startPreview()). Preview will be stopped after the image is taken;
>   callers must call startPreview() again if they want to re-start
>   preview or take more pictures. This should not be called between
>   start() and stop(). After calling this method, you must not call
>   startPreview() or take another picture until the JPEG callback has
>   returned.