# Android camera-preview on surfaceview

Tags: android-camera, surfaceview

I developed an app which uses the camera on my android-phone. If I click a button to start the preview it shows the preview on a surface-view and then it takes every X seconds a picture.

My problem is this: The preview does not show the whole area that is in the picture if it's taken, so it seems like it's zoomed in. When `onPictureTaken` is executed, it automatically shows the taken picture for a short time on the surface-view, but then it isn't zoomed in.
switching to the preview again, the zoom is there again.

Does anyone know how to show the whole area also in preview-mode?

**Update: My camaera-settings:**

```
camera = Camera.open();

Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

String res = sp.getString("res", "1280 × 720"); 
String[] dim = res.split(" × "); 

int width = Integer.parseInt(dim[0]);
int height = Integer.parseInt(dim[1]);

params.setPreviewSize(width, height);
params.setPictureSize(width, height);
```

Comment: Maybe you use a wide resolution for preview and 4x3 resolution for capture?

Comment: `camera.setPreviewSize()` and `camera.setPictureSize()` get both the same dimensions (1920 x 1080) and both support these dimensions

Comment: You don't set zoom-in for the camera, do you? BTW, which device is that?

Comment: No, I didn't set any zoom-settings. I added my cameraParams to the question (I didn't add flash- and focus-settings). It's a Samsung Galaxy S2+

Comment: You call `camera.setParams(params)` after the piece you pasted, did you? You did not set the zoom, but did you check the zoom?

Comment: Yes, after flash- and focus-settings I call `camera.setParameters(params);`. I didn't check zoom via `getZoom` but I tried `setZoom(0)` and nothing changed.

Comment: One last idea: if you try preview callback, is the field of view same as the picture you capture, or as the preview displayed on the surface? And one "bonus": try to use a 4:3 resolution for both preview and capture, e.g. 640x480.

Comment: I set the height of my FrameLayout to 50dp to see my test-button and then I don't have the problem with this zooming preview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29932/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-recode)

Comment: I believe that this actually is a duplicate of [Android (Camera) - How to syncronize stopPreview() with onPictureTaken()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924038/android-camera-how-to-syncronize-stoppreview-with-onpicturetaken)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because there is a difference between the shown recorded image and the saved image (only if client is moving). But my preview is cropped in 1080p (the final image is like it should be)

Comment: Their problem was that <b>the still picture actually shown after the stopPreview method is called DOES NOT correspond to the one that I get in the byte array of the onPictureTaken method</b>. Specific details depend on the device and (as we learn from your research) capture resolution.

Comment: Yes, I read that, but that's not my problem because the final image (automatically shown, stopPreview not needed) shows the image that's saved, but the preview does only show a cropped version of this.

Comment: I am used to calling stopPreview() (this was required before Honeycomb). I wonder - if you would call stopPreview() before taking picture, will this resolve your problem?

Comment: I don't think so, because the preview is cropped and not the final image, so the taken image needs no change.