# Android camera - how to prevent captured image from showing?

Tags: android, camera, preview

I am developing an app that shows a camera preview, takes a picture, and then shows the picture to the user. Since the window size, preview size and camera capture size do not match up, the app crops the resulting image to the correct aspect (and then scales it to the window dimension) before showing it.

The problem I have is this:

At the call to Camera.takePicture() the preview surface is filled with a copy of the captured image. This image is in a different aspect than what was previously shown in preview window, so the image looks stretched. This image is shown for a second before the app can show a new window with the cropped/scaled image.

Is there a way to prevent this last frame from filling the preview window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android (Camera) - How to syncronize stopPreview() with onPictureTaken()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924038/android-camera-how-to-syncronize-stoppreview-with-onpicturetaken)

Comment: The answer provides a solution to a different problem; presenting an image after the photo has been taken. The problem I am describing here is that the last shown frame of the preview is of a different aspect than the previous ones.

Comment: No, their problem was not about presenting the captured image, but rather the disruption to preview video stream that is caused by picture capture. Actually, the answer states that there is no clean solution to the problem, and describes some partial workarounds. The same workarounds may happen to be useful for your problem.

Comment: Specifically, if you call `stopPreview()` prior to `takePicture()`, you will not have last frame filling the preview window

Comment: This shouldn't work, or it only works by accident; a precondition for calling takePicture() is that the preview is active.

Comment: right; stopPreview is called internally by the framework

Comment: Hi, i too have the same issue. but this issue is there only in Sony devices. please update if you found any solution for this issue.

Comment: I did not find a solution, instead I covered the preview with a blank screen until the new image was presented.