# StopPreview camera show black screen

Tags: android, camera

I'm programming a custom camera in a surface view, when I press a button a picture is taken and the image of the camera is frozen when I call to

> camera.stopPreview()

this works fine in some phones, but in android version 2.3.6 don't works, only show the view in black color, if I remove the call stopPreview the image is frozen only in the phones with 2.3.6, somebody know why and can help me?

UPDATE:
In some phones don't need use camera.stopPreview() because when I take a picture the image is frozen automatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android (Camera) - How to syncronize stopPreview() with onPictureTaken()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924038/android-camera-how-to-syncronize-stoppreview-with-onpicturetaken) or [The way to freeze the camera preview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8345591/192373)

Comment: Note that the [Camera class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) says explicitly: *After taking a picture, preview display will have stopped. To take more photos, call startPreview() again first.* Maybe, this is not correct for the 2.3.6 device.

Comment: I read the documentation and I don't understand why this happen. At the moment I have this: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>10) camera.stopPreview(); (But it is only one patch)

Comment: Let me repeat: per *the book*, you don't need to call `stopPreview()` after `takePicture()`. There is not contract, though, that the SurfaceView will show the last preview image, or be black, or whatever. That's why the linked answers suggest to open an ImageView and fill it explicitly.

Comment: If I don't call stopPreview() in the galaxy S4 the screen doesn't freeze

Comment: Only Samsung is responsible for buggy behavior of their device (unless you use a custom MOD on S4). Anyways, this was a side note only.

Comment: The same happen with Sony Xperia